# Проверить строку на наличие специальных символов и цифр (Java)

Tags: java

```
System.out.print("Введите слова одной строкой через пробел:   ");
String input = sc.nextLine();
```

Ввожу строку из нескольких слов. Как сделать так, чтобы выполнялась проверка строки, чтобы в строке были только буквы, никаких символов (,./!?:%;...) и цифр?

Пробовал вот так, но проверяется только одно слово.

```
if(!input.matches("[а-яА-Я]+"))
{
    System.out.println("Строка содержит не только буквы");
}
else
{
    System.out.println("Строка содержит буквы");
}
```

Comment: так: "[^a-яA-Я ]" - забыли символ ``^``, и символ ``+`` не надо

Comment: чтобы проверялось не одно слово, нужно в регулярке в квадратных скобках добавить пробел

Comment: Не работает. Добавил птичку и пробел в квадратных скобках. Ввожу слово "программа5" , пишет что строка содержит только буквы

Comment: попробуйте пройтись обычным циклом

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нужно просто указать, что у вас должно состоять предложение только из букв или пробелов:

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Введите слова одной строкой через пробел:   ");
String input = scanner.nextLine();
System.out.println(input.matches("[\\p{L}| ]+"));
```

Comment: Если хотите, чтобы кейс с пустой строкой тоже был валидный, то тогда просто в регулярном выражении нужно поменять + на * "[\\p{L}| ]*".

Comment: Для кириллицы этот способ не работает.

Comment: Можно дописать, сейчас исправлю

Comment: У меня с кириллицей работает, но если бы не работало, то можно было бы прописать так "(?ui)[\\p{L}| ]"

Comment: У меня почему-то не работает. И второй вариант тоже :/

Comment: Скиньте, пожалуйста, пример вводимой строки, чтобы я у себя воспроизвел.

Comment: Да любая. "ррар", "рвлвш иврщ вр" и т.д.

Comment: Я не знаю, почему у вас это не прошло, но у меня все эти варианты проходят.

Comment: Похоже, какая-то системная проблема. Даже если я явно указываю допустимые символы (например ``"[фывапролджэ]+"``) и ввожу только их, то проверка все равно не проходит. С латиницей проблем нет.

Comment: Супер, всё работает. Спасибо)